# Windows Server 2008r2 Certificate services

Tags: ad-certificate-services

I have a windows server 2008 r2 domain named ITTraining.local promoted to dc and another server which is added in ITTraining domain and on which i am installing Certificate services role, but while doing i am getting the enterprise CA option greyed out, i searched and i found to do
"In order to install an Enterprise CA, you must be a member of either Enterprise Admins or Domain Admins in the forest root domain (either directly or through a group nesting)."

but i am not sure how to do this can someone please guide me

Comment: Login with your domain account, like `Domain\useraccount`, not by using local account.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the computer added to the domain is seen as a normal client. Go into `Active Directory Users and Computers` and see under the entry for that server and add it to the domain computers group if it isnt. I would also add it to the certificate group, will have to look in the list of groups for something related to certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Enterprise CA installation being authorized under the domain account for example `ITTraining\Administrator` that is in one of domain groups `ITTraining\Enterprise Admins` or `ITTraining\Domain Admins`.

As suggested @xR34P3Rx, you can check which users belong to this groups in *Active Directory Users and Computers* snap (at least you can found it on your domain controller). These groups are located in the root domain in `cn=BUILTIN` container.

If you do not have access to the domain controller, you should ask for help from it's admin, because without him you do not succeed setup Enterprise CA.